# Reformulation of Goldbach's Conjecture as optimization problem correct?

Tags: number-theory, partial-differential-equations, optimization, asymptotics, goldbachs-conjecture

### Question

I think I managed to reformulate a **stronger** version of Goldbach's conjecture as an optimization problem:

$$ \frac{\partial F_n}{\partial a_n} = \frac{\partial F_n}{\partial \overline a_n} = \frac{\partial F_n }{\partial \lambda_n}=0$$

Where:

$$  F_n =  |a_n|^2 - \lambda_n  \frac{\sin(\pi |b_n|^2)}{|b_n|^2} $$

$$ (\sum_{r=1}^\infty |a_r|^2 x^{2r+1})^2 = \sum_{r=1}^\infty |b_r|^2 x^{2r+4}$$

Is this formulation correct? Is this stronger version convincing? Does it have any interesting implications?

### Background

We are all familiar with Goldbach's Conjecture any even number greater then $2$ is expressible as the sum of primes. Expressing it combinatorically (without the case of $p_1$):

$$ (\sum_{r=2}^\infty x^{p_r})^2 = \sum_{r=1}^\infty b_r x^{2r+4} $$

where, $p_r$ is the r'th prime and $ b_r \neq 0 $.

I recently thought that a **stronger version** as a limit of $n \to \infty$:

"The minimum number of elements in  a set required to construct the even numbers $<n$ as a sum of it's elements is the primes numbers"

Expressing the above as equations:

$$
 \min(|a_r|^2)  =
  \begin{cases} 
      1    \hfill & 2r+1=\text{prime number} \\
      0 \hfill & \text{ otherwise} \\
  \end{cases}
$$

Under the constraints:

$$ (\sum_{r=1}^\infty |a_r|^2 x^{2r+1})^2 = \sum_{r=1}^\infty |b_r|^2 x^{2r+4}$$

and, $b_r$ must be an a natural number

$$ \frac{\sin(\pi |b_n|^2)}{|b_n|^2} = 0 $$

### For example

By comparing coefficients of $x$:

$|a_1|^4=|b_1|^2$

Using Lagrange multipliers:

$$ F_1= |a_1|^2 - \lambda_1 \frac{\sin(\pi |a_1|^4)}{|a_1|^4} = a_1 \overline a_1 -  \lambda_1 \frac{\sin(\pi (a_1 \overline a_1)^2)}{(a_1 \overline a_1)^2} $$

Where $ \overline a_n  $ is the complex conjugate of $a_n$.

Now, finding the minimum

$$ \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial a_1} = \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial \overline a_1} = \frac{\partial F_1 }{\partial \lambda_1}=0$$

This gives us the following equations:
$$ \overline a_1  -  \lambda_1 ( 2 \pi  \frac{\cos(\pi( a_1 \overline a_1)^2)}{ a_1} - 2 \frac{\sin(\pi (a_1 \overline a_1)^2)}{(a_1^2) (\overline a_1)^3} ) = 0 $$

$$  a_1  -  \lambda_1 ( 2 \pi  \frac{\cos(\pi( a_1 \overline a_1)^2)}{ \overline a_1} - 2 \frac{\sin(\pi (a_1 \overline a_1)^2)}{(\overline a_1^2) ( a_1)^3} ) = 0 $$
$$ \frac{\sin(\pi (a_1 \overline a_1)^2)}{(a_1 \overline a_1)^2} = 0 $$

Solving the above:

$ |a_1|^2=1$ and $ \lambda_1 = -\frac{1}{2 \pi} $

Comment: When you define $F_n$, there appears a summation indexed with $n$. I guess that's some kind of a typo?

Comment: There are many sets $A$ of integers such that $A + A$ contains all even integers.  All are countably infinite, of course, so there's nothing special about the primes there.

Comment: Your statement "The minimum number of elements...is the prime numbers" is not coherent; "the prime numbers" is not a number.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to word it due that fact and said as a limit of finite sets going to infinity. By that I mean if I want all the even  numbers less than (say)  $n =14$ excluding $2$ and $4$. I need $3,5,7$$

Comment: Then  take $n$ as a very very large number $\to \infty$

Comment: Note that $(\sum_{r=2}^\infty x^{p_r})^2 = \sum_{r=1}^\infty b_r x^{2r+4}$ does nothing to restrict to the addition of just two primes.

(Side note, in your example, you only need $\{3,5,7\}$)

Comment: But the Goldbach conjecture does restrict to the addition of two primes. Your sum $(\sum_{r=2}^\infty x^{p_r})^2$ will count sums of any number of primes, and it not even restricted to just even powers, as you have written.

Comment: Which is why I wrote a "stronger" version I think it should be restricted to the even numbers as all the primes except $2$ are odd.

Comment: There's nothing special about the primes.  For example, you can represent every even number from $4$ to  $56$  as the sum of two (not necessarily distinct) members of $\{ 2,4, 8, 12, 16, 18, 36, 38\}$, a set of cardinality 8.  You can't do it with a set of $8$ primes: you need at least $10$.

Comment: I see your point ... Out of curiousity how did you generate those numbers? And is there a way to be sure this will be true for say larger and larger numbers?

Comment: I used an SMT solver (z3).

Comment: @RobertIsrael After thinking some more ... One way of disproving my conjecture would be  $ (\sum x^p_i)^2 \sim 1/((x-1) \ln(1-x))^2 $ as $x \to 1^- $ because of the last page of: http://mathstat.dal.ca/~antoniov/notes/boundaryasymp.pdf if you manage to show that some $b_i$ exists with $(\sum x^b_i)^2 $ grows less than that you would have disproved my idea

Comment: ** It should be $p_i$ and $b_i$

Comment: @AnantSaxena In general it only takes $O(\sqrt{n})$ numbers to generate everything from $1$ to $n$.  But there are far more prime numbers than this.

Comment: This is related to the [postage stamp problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postage_stamp_problem).  Some estimates are known there.  In particular, the Challis paper says, if I interpret it correctly, that with a set of $n$ positive integers you can get all positive integer sums up to $2 n^2/7$.

Comment: Spin off question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632870/existence-of-a-gx-that-can-generate-all-the-even-numbers

Comment: Repost from spin-off question: ... I would like to elaborate.... I don't think we should first construct $ \sum_{k=1}^n x^{y_k}$ and then see if it grows less quicker than $ \sum_{k=1}^n x^{p_i} $ ... Because the sequence we are interested is $\lim_{x \to 1^-}\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n x^{y_k}$ however the sequence you seem to be proposing is $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{ x \to 1 } \sum_{k=1}^n x^{y_k}$ (Notice the swap of the limits ... )

Comment: @ErickWong the above post is relevant and I think shows your idea to be inadequate ... (Please correct me if my understanding is wrong)

Comment: @AnantSaxena Huh?  I didn't suggest any idea.  I'm only addressing your thinking that "The minimum number of elements in a set required to construct the even numbers $<n$ as a sum of it's elements is the primes numbers".  It is wrong, and it only becomes more wrong as $n$ increases: the minimum number of elements is $O(\sqrt{n})$ which is far smaller than $O(n/\log n)$ of the primes.

Comment: Let us say your series is $ Z(x,n)= \sum_{r=1}^n x^{b_r} $ which constructs all even numbers $<n$ when squared ...Taking $\lim_{ x\to 1^-}  Z(x,n) \sim O(\sqrt n) $  Now taking another limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{ x\to 1^-}  Z(x,n) \sim O(\sqrt n) $ .... However if we want ALL the even numbers we need a series such that $B(x,n) = \sum_{r=1}^n x^{k_r} $ where $k_r$ is the r'th term in such a series .. $B(x,n) = \sum_{r=1}^n x^{k_r} $ Taking the limit to the $n$'th term ... 
$ \lim_{n \to \infty} B(x,n) = B(x)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{k_r} $ and now: $\lim_{x \to 1^-} B(x) = ? $

Comment: The last point of the comment has been addressed over here  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636054/swapping-the-order-of-limits-in-combinatoric ... Thank you