# Existence of a $G(x)$ that can generate all the even numbers?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, goldbachs-conjecture

### Question

This is a "spin-off" question of: [Reformulation of Goldbach's Conjecture as optimization problem correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632270/reformulation-of-goldbachs-conjecture-as-optimization-problem-correct)

I was wondering if a function  existed such that:

$$ G(x)^2 = (\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^{b_i})^2 =\sum_{m=3}^\infty A_m x^{2m}$$

Where $A_m$ is an integer $\neq 0$ and $b_i$ is an arbitrary natural number.

And grows less quicker than:

$$ \lim_{x \to 1^-} (\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^{b_i})^2 < \frac{1}{((1-x)\ln(1-x))^2}  $$

### Background

We know $\sum x^{p_i} \sim  \frac{1}{(x-1)\ln(1-x)} $

as $ x \nearrow 1 $ and $p_i$ is the $i$'th prime

as explained in the last page of http://mathstat.dal.ca/~antoniov/notes/boundaryasymp.pdf

And if Goldbach's conjecture is true:

$$ (\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^{p_i})^2 =\sum_{m=3}^\infty A_m x^{2m}$$

Where $A_m$ is an integer $\neq 0$

So I was wondering if there were another set of numbers $b_i$ that could satisfy  Goldbach's conjecture but grow slower than $\sum x^{p_i}$

Comment: If $G^2$ is to be an even function, then for any $x$, it must be the case that $G(-x)=\pm G(x)$. If $G$ is analytic, I think this forces $G$ to either be even or odd. That would mean your $b_i$ are either all even numbers or all odd numbers.

Comment: @alex.jordan If Goldbach's conjecture is true then $G(x)$ can also be all the primes

Comment: Actually now that I think more, your $G$ must be odd and begin $G(x)=x^3+x^5+\cdots$. It's the only way to get $G(x)^2=A_3x^6+A_4x^8+\cdots$. Whether the next term in $G(x)$ is $x^7$ or $x^9$ is a choice.

Comment: I never claimed the collection of $b_i$ had to be all of the odd numbers. I said _all of the $b_i$_ had to be odd numbers.

Comment: Sorry my bad, didn't read the comment properly

Comment: @user1952009  ... 

If I understand you correctly $\sum_{k=1}^n x^{y_k}$ and then compare to $\sum_{k=1}^n x^{p_n}$ ... However I think to prove the conjecture we need  $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_{k=1}^n x^{y_k}$ and not  $ \lim_{x \to 1^-} \lim_{n \to \infty } \sum_{k=1}^n x^{y_k}$ ...

Comment: After re-reading the above comment it sounds incoherent and wrong in some places  ... So I would like to elaborate.... I don't think we should first construct $ \sum_{k=1}^n x^{y_k}$ and then see if it grows less quicker than $ \sum_{k=1}^n x^{p_i} $ ... Because the sequence we are interested is $\lim_{x \to 1^-}\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n x^{y_k}$ however the sequence you seem to be proposing is $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{ x \to 1 } \sum_{k=1}^n x^{y_k}$ (Notice the swap of the limits ... )

Comment: forget it, I'm not sure anymore it is easy to construct an "optimal" sequence of odd numbers such that every even number can be written as the sum of two terms of that sequence. do you know https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_number ?

Comment: Nope, just read of it ... seems interesting ... Is it related to my question somehow?

Comment: I think it's likely that at a minimum, there is some prime that you could omit from the set of primes, although that would not make the inequality substantial.

Comment: @AnantSaxena Please see this old paper of Erdős, particularly section 2: http://ftp.math-inst.hu/~p_erdos/1956-17.pdf.  If you read it very carefully you will see there is a probabilistic construction of a sequence that satisfies "every integer is the sum of two elements in the sequence", but only requires $O(\sqrt{n \log n})$ elements up to $n$.  It will certainly grow slower than the generating function for primes.