# What are the smallest amount of numbers required to generate all the even numbers?

Tags: number-theory, limits, asymptotics

### Viewpoint 1

To generate the even numbers $<n$ the smallest amount of numbers we need about $O (\sqrt{n})$ (by summing only $2$ elements)

Hence, consider the series:

$$ ( \sum_{r=1}^n x^{b_r})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x^{b_i + b_j}= \sum_{r=2}^n c_{r} x^{2r}  $$

where $b_i$ is an arbitrary natural number.

For example for $n= 57$

$$ (x^2 + x^4 + x^8 + x^{12} + x^{16} + x^{18}  + x^{36}+ x^{38})^2= \sum_{r=1}^{28} c_r x^{2r} $$ 
and then taking the square root and the limit:

$$ \lim_{x \to 1^-} ( \sum_{r=1}^n x^{b_r}) = \sqrt{\sum_{r=2}^\infty c_{r} x^{2r}} = \text{number of terms}$$

Proceeding in our example:

$$ \lim_{x \to {1^-}}(x^2 + x^4 + x^8 + x^{12} + x^{16} + x^{18}  + x^{36}+ x^{38})^2= 8 \approx \sqrt{57} $$

Hence, to generate all the even numbers:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty }\lim_{x \to 1^-} ( \sum_{r=1}^n x^{b_r})^2  \sim O(\sqrt{n})$$

### Viewpoint 2

However I do not think we can say that is the case to generate **all** the even numbers.

We need:
Let the series which generates all even numbers be

$$ (\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n  x^{a_r})^2= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x^{a_i + a_j} = \sum_{r=2}^\infty c_{r} x^{2r} $$

where $a_i$ is an arbitrary natural number. 
Assuming Goldbach's conjecture is true we can use the following we can use the following example:

$$ (\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n  x^{p_r})^2 = \sum_{r=2}^\infty c_{r} x^{2r} $$

Where $p_r$ is the $r$'th prime

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sum_{r=1}^n  x^{p_r})^2 = \sum_{r=2}^\infty c_{r} x^{2r} $$

And the number of terms would approach required to generate the even powered series:

$$ \implies  \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sum_{r=1}^n  x^{a_r}) = \sqrt{\sum_{r=2}^\infty c_r x^{2r} }= \text{number of terms}\sim \alpha(x)  $$

$x \to 1^-$

Again proceeding with our example:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sum_{r=1}^n  x^{p_r})\sim \frac{1}{(x-1)\ln(1-x)} $$

where $x \to 1^-$

Where $ \alpha(x) $ would  be the amount to generate all the even numbers. Hence, the number of elements we need are:

$$ \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n a_r x^r \sim \alpha(x)  $$

where $x \to 1^-$

### Question

Which viewpoint is correct? and why?

P.S: This is related to [Reformulation of Goldbach's Conjecture as optimization problem correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632270/reformulation-of-goldbachs-conjecture-as-optimization-problem-correct) however I did not have enough space in the comments to dispute my misconception/concept.

### Point of Dispute (Edit)

How does one extend the finite case $< n $ to $n \to \infty $

Viewpoint 2 seems to suggest they should have no connection.

Comment: I'm not sure what your notation is implying, but consider that you can generate all the even numbers from 2-2046 by summing various combinations of 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512 and 1024 for instance, much less than sqrt(2048) distinct numbers? Or maybe even 2, 6, 18, 54, 162, 486, 1458 in a ternary system?

Comment: Umm ... You can't generate $14$ as the sum of $2$ numbers in your sequence ... As for the notation please ask which part is badly written (I'm assuming that's the reason for the down-votes as well)?

Comment: I've not downvoted (or voted at all) - I'm not that familiar with the notation. You can generate 14 by either 2+4+8, or 18+2-6 depending on what sequence you're using. It's probable that I've completely missed the point here

Comment: @sjb hopefully the question is clearer now .... If something is still unclear please let me know ...

Comment: What you want to do is do a websearch for $$\rm additive\ basis\ of\ order\ 2$$

Comment: Can you explain the manipulations you're doing in viewpoint 2 more explicitly?  What is $\alpha(x)$?  How does what you're concluding contradict viewpoint 1?

Comment: @EricWofsey The ending contradict's viewpoint 1 as the order of limits are the swapped $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{x \to 1^-} \neq \lim_{x \to 1^-} \lim_{n \to \infty}$... $\alpha(x)$ is defined via that that asymptotic equation ... We are interested in $\alpha(1^-)$ as that would in some sense give you the number of terms ...

Comment: Also the $\sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{p_r}$ is explained here (last page of): http://mathstat.dal.ca/~antoniov/notes/boundaryasymp.pdf

Comment: Neither of the two limits you're talking about actually exists (both go to $\infty$)...I don't understand what you're finding incompatible here.  And it doesn't make sense to compare their asymptotic behavior because one is a function of $n$ and the other is a function of $x$ (assuming you're first taking the inner limit, and then looking at the asymptotics as you approach the outer limit).

Comment: Lets way I wanted the to construct all the even numbers with $f_1(x)^2$ and I try $f_1$ where
$ f_1(x) = x^3 + x^5+x^7 + x^9 \dots = \frac{x^3}{1-x^2} $ ... Now if I try $f_2(x)$ with
$ f_2(x) = x^3 + x^5 +x^7 + x^{11} + \dots = \sum x^{p_r}$ Now comparing both at $\lim_{1^-} f(x)$ 
We note (in some sense):
$ \frac{x^3}{1-x^2} > \frac{1}{(x-1)\ln(1-x)}$

Comment: OK, but in viewpoint 1 you're computing a totally different quantity (you're setting $x=1$ for a fixed $n$ and letting $n$ get large, rather than taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ and then letting $x$ approach $1$).  So there's no reason to expect to get the same answer. (What would it even mean to get the same answer?  In viewpoint 1 the variable is $n$ which is going to $\infty$, and in viewpoint 2 the variable is $x$ which is going to $1$.  Also, viewpoint 1 only gives a lower bound.)

Comment: It's actually related to refute the argument given by Eric Wong: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632270/reformulation-of-goldbachs-conjecture-as-optimization-problem-correct?lq=1 .... 
the minimum number of elements is $O(\sqrt{n})$ which is far smaller than $O(n/logn)$ of the primes .... I don't think his argument works for $\infty$

Comment: To summarize his argument: the primes cannot be the smallest set to construct the even numbers as they grow $O(n/\ln(n)$ and the smallest set required to construct the even numbers grow as $O \sqrt{n}$

Comment: I think you need to clarify what it means to you for a viewpoint to be "correct".

Comment: @EricWofsey After some introspection I think it's a difference of definition of number of terms (which happens to coincide in the finite case) ... Which one is correct and why? "Correct" = relevant to the criticism

Comment: Well, why do you think there can only be one correct viewpoint?  There is no intrinsic meaning to "number of terms" until we choose to define it, and both definitions may be perfectly reasonable even if they are not equivalent.

Comment: But doesn't the criticism made in definition/viewpoint 1 get invalidated in viewpoint 2?? This is how I see things ... I made statement $A$:
$ \text{Viewpoint 1} \implies A \text{ is true} $ or we have:
$ \text{Viewpoint 2} \implies A \text{ is false} $ ... I'm sure it has to be one or the other ...

Comment: The statement $A$ is not a precise mathematical statement.  You can make it precise in multiple different ways, and in some ways it may be true and in others it may be false.  There's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: So is the statement "there exists no $b_r$ such that $(\sum_{r=1} x^{b_r})^2 = \sum_{r=2}^\infty a_r x^{2r}$ with $a_r \neq 0$ and $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum  x^{b_r } < \frac{1}{(x-1)(\ln(1-x))}  $" is therefore not refuable by viewpoint 1?

Comment: @AnantSaxena I understand that it might take a denser sequence than $O(\sqrt{n})$ to generate all even numbers rather than being able to choose a different finite set for each $n$.  However, my comment in the other other question shows that this difference is extremely slight: you still only need $O(\sqrt{n \log n})$ terms up to $n$ to get an infinite sequence.  That's insignificant compared to how much denser the primes are.

Comment: @ErickWong How do you extend the finite case $<n$ to the $n \to \infty$ case? Viewpoint 2 suggests doing this would not be trivial ...

Comment: @AnantSaxena Like I said, I already described this in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632870/existence-of-a-gx-that-can-generate-all-the-even-numbers#comment3334851_1632870.  Please read that carefully before jumping to conclusions.  It is indeed non-trivial but it is a well-known probabilistic construction.

Comment: Umm ... @ErickWong thank you for the links (I think a "Problems and results in additive number theory for dummies" is required for me ... If you know of any such reference (for beginners) do not hesitate to tell) ... But more on topic let your series be $ \sum_r x^{a_r} \sim G(x)$ as $x \nearrow 1$ where $G(x)$ is the asymptotic relationship can you tell me what $G(x)$ would be ... Sorry I'm still stuck up on view $2$

Comment: @AnantSaxena See my answer in another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636054/swapping-the-order-of-limits-in-combinatoric/1636511#1636511

Answer (score 2):

Given $n$, choose $K$ even such that $K^2>2n$, and use the numbers $$2,4,6,8,\dots,K-4,K-2,K,2K,3K,4K,\dots,(K/2)K$$ That uses about $K$ numbers, where $K$ is about $\sqrt2\sqrt n$.

One can do better than that, but that's enough to show you that $c\sqrt n$ can be achieved for some constant $c$.

Much, much more information is available by following my comment and searching for $$\rm additive\ basis\ of\ order\ 2$$

Comment: I did search $\text{additive basis of order } 2$ but alot of it went over my head (I'm only a physics undergraduate) ... Perhaps you could also recommend me something that also addresses my edit? (I would like to learn more about this) ... Thank you

Comment: So pick out something you found out about additive bases of order 2, something you didn't understand, and ask about it. I can't guess where your difficulties lie. Anyway, just because the primes have counting function $n/\log n$, that doesn't mean every additive basis has to be as numerous as the primes. You can use the idea in my answer to construct a much thinner basis, even in the infinite case, by repeating the construction on larger and larger scales.

Comment: I apologize for being incoherent ... But why is viewpoint 2 wrong? (it's alot more intuitive to me)  ... I have demonstrated that both cases differ in the order of their limits so I think that would imply one cannot extend it to the infinite case trivially ...

Comment: I think what's wrong with viewpoint 2 is that you jump from "[Goldbach says that] you can use the primes to generate the evens" to "you *must* use the primes to generate the evens." It's generally believed that the primes generate the evens many times over, that is, that every large even can be expressed in many, many ways as a sum of two primes. The primes are a wasteful, uneconomical way of generating the evens. Much thinner sets – $\sqrt{n\log n}$ sets – can do it, too.

Comment: The only problem I had with that was this was an observation of the finite case which I wasn't sure if one could extend to the infinite case ... However, my concerns have been addressed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636054/swapping-the-order-of-limits-in-combinatoric?noredirect=1