# Swapping the order of limits in combinatoric?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, limits, asymptotics

**Part** $A$

Let a power series be $ \sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{a_r}$

Now, we are interested square of the power series with the condition:

$$ \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{a_m + a_n} =   \sum_{r=3}^\infty C_r x^{2r} $$

where $C_r \neq 0$ and we want the limit to approach infinity as slow as possible:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{a_r} \sim G(x,a_1,a_2,\dots)$$

$x \to 1^-$

**Part** $B$:

We note that the minimum number of terms required to construct all the even numbers less than $n$ is $O(\sqrt{n})$. This is also true when $n = \infty$ $(?)$. Hence, we construct a ploynomial such that:

$$ (\sum_{r=1}^n x^{a_r})^2 = \sum_{r=3}^{2n} C_r x^{2r}$$

Taking $\lim_{x \to 1^-}$

$$ \lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_{r=1}^n x^{a_r} = O(\sqrt{n}) $$

By taking $ n \to \infty $

$$ \lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_{r=1}^n x^{a_r} = O(\sqrt{n}) $$

We note $n \to \infty$

$$ \lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_{r=1}^n x^{a_r} = O(\sqrt{n}) < \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_{r=1}^n x^{p_r} \sim \frac{n}{\ln(n)}$$

**Part** $C$:

Upon closer examination of part $B$ no matter how large $n$ may become $n < \infty$. Hence, it will never include **all** the even numbers and taking $n \to \infty$ (as rightly noticed by Thomas in the comments). The right way to proceed would be:

$$ \lim_{x \to 1^-} \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n x^{a_r} $$

### Question

Can someone construct an explicit example of $a_n$

where,

$$ (\sum_{r=1}^n x^{a_r})^2 = \sum_{r=3}^{2n} C_r x^{2r} $$

and $C_r \neq 0$

And its limit approachs $\infty$ much slower than

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n x^{a_r} <  \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=2}^n x^{p_r} \sim \frac{1}{(x-1)\ln(1-x)}$$

where $x \to 1^-$

where $p_r$ is the $r$'th prime.

Note: If Goldbach's conjecture is true then:

$$ (\sum_{r=2}^n x^{p_r})^2  = \sum_{r=3}^\infty C_r x^{2r} $$

P.S: I've tried asking this before however I got estimates in $f(n)$ and not $f(x)$. Hence, I decided to include part B and  part C

Comment: Are you requiring that $n$ be a sum of two elements of the set, or of any number?  And are you requiring the sum to be of two distinct elements of the set or can an element be repeated?

Comment: It's very hard to tell which are the statements you are asking about, and which are commentaries. Also, "construct?" This question is kind of a mess.

Comment: $n$ is some sense the number of terms as $n \to \infty$  ....  The sum of two distinct elements can be repeated: For example: $ 7+3 = 5+5=10$

Comment: So have we determined that it has to be a sum of two elements of the set?  That's still ambiguous, but I'm assuming the answer is yes otherwise the answer becomes trivial.  You should clarify this in the statement.

Comment: It's also not possible for $\lim_{x\to 1-}$ to be anything other than $+\infty$.

Comment: I'd write $f(x)\sum_i x^{a_i}$ then $f(x)\sim G(x)$ as $x\to 1-$. Don't write $\lim$, that means something else.

Comment: It is a bit absurd to write that $O(\sqrt{n})$ is a possible when $n=\infty$. That is a misuse of notation. You have jumped from the case of infinite power series to questions of polynomials satisfying the problem for $2k<n$, but that's a different question. It's also not clear how you can achieve $O(\sqrt{n})$ for all $n$, but even if you could, that wouldn't tell you anything about the infinite case.

Comment: Solving the case for each finite $n$ does not let you come up with a minimal case that handles the infinite case, unless it is somehow incremental - that the the set if $\{a_i\}$ for $n$ is a subset of the set of $\{a_i\}$ for some $m>n$. using the same $a_i$ is going to cause you confusion.

Comment: That was precisely my point! (read the P.S at the end) ... But I don't think I could convey it so I thought I must have been wrong decided to write another similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635701/what-are-the-smallest-amount-of-numbers-required-to-generate-all-the-even-number

Comment: He also comments in his answer: "You can use the idea in my answer to construct a much thinner basis, even in the infinite case"

Comment: I think you mean to start the summation $\sum C_rx^{2r}$ at $r=3$, not $r=2$.  That's certainly the case at the very end of the post, where you're squaring $x^3+x^5+x^7+x^{11}+\cdots$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erdos's construction in http://ftp.math-inst.hu/~p_erdos/1956-17.pdf gives an expected $\sum_{n\in S} x^s = \sum_{n \ge 1} C \sqrt{\frac{\log n}{n}}x^n$, which if I'm not mistaken, is asymptotic to $$O\big(\sqrt{\frac{|\log (1-x)|}{1-x}}\big)$$ as $x\to 1^-$.  This is obviously quite close to optimal, however it is a probabilistic construction, and you asked for an explicit sequence.

An explicit sequence is given by the set

$$S = \{n \ge 0: \text{the base-$3$ representation of $n$ consists of digits $0,1$}\}.$$  Every nonnegative number, even or odd, can be represented as a sum of two elements of $S$ (you could restrict to odd values only, by applying the transform $x\mapsto 2x+1$, it's really not important).

The number of elements of $S$ up to $3^k$ is $2^k$, so the number of elements of $S$ up to $n$ is $\asymp n^{\log 2/\log 3} \approx n^{0.631}$.  Note this is an order of magnitude, not an asymptotic (there is no asymptotic counting function for $S$ as it goes through long gaps without any elements) but it is still much, much thinner than the primes.  Consequently, I would expect the order of growth for $\sum_{n \in S} x^S$ to be about equal to $O((1-x)^{-0.631})$.

I suggest you read up on [Tauberian theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem) as a tool for converting between estimates for the counting function of a set and estimates for the growth rate of the generating function.  I think this is the concept you are struggling to describe adequately -- hopefully someone else can provide a better reference.